# Adding css file url to nuxt.config.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to add my own CSS which is composed of output of Sass but I do no know how to as per the documentation say

```
module.exports = {
  css: [
    // Load a Node.js module directly (here it's a Sass file)
    'bulma',
    // CSS file in the project
    '@/assets/css/main.css',
    // SCSS file in the project
    '@/assets/css/main.scss'
  ]
}
```

but when I opened nuxt.config.js I find the following format which is totally different

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'nexus',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** Run ESLint on save
    */
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add my own css link to that file?

Answer (score 0):

What is different? You just need to add css section to your nuxt.config. that's if you want to process your css thorough nuxt/webpack.

If you want to just add static css file to head you do it in head section.